# Android: Set width and height for a drawable

Tags: android, expandablelistview

In my application i use groupIndicator for an Expandable List View but images are not show correctly and have elongation, how can i set width and height for images?

this is my codes:

```
<ExpandableListView
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:id="@+id/expandableListView"
            android:groupIndicator="@drawable/group_indicator"/>
```

group_indicator.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/plus" android:state_empty="true"/>
    <item android:drawable="@drawable/minus" android:state_expanded="true"/>    
</selector>
```

Comment: You can add a screenshot showing the problem. It could help users in giving the right answers

Comment: Are the drawables resources or shapes ?

Comment: @EmilPana drawables are images that i add them to my project.

Answer (score 0):

Create 9-patch images for your plus and minus drawables which you have used in group_indicator.xml.

Comment: can you explain how i can do it?